# Getting "System.Int32 is not defined or imported" in Visual Studio 2017 with Unity

Tags: unity, visual-studio

I have been working well with Unity 2018.2 & VS2015, the only issue was the constant VS2015 reloading but I was putting up with it. When I upgraded to Unity 2018.3 an issue came up when trying to start debugging on VS2015:
[image]

I searched online and the only discussion I found recommended upgrading to VS2017, but when I switched to it I got a billion errors in the solution regarding basic types such as int or object not being defined:
[image]

These errors are only in VS2017, the Unity editor reports everything being fine. Can anyone help me fix either version? Thank you.

Comment: Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48069685) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47220386).

Comment: @Draco18s unfortunately neither solution worked

Comment: Odd. I have no experience with this kind of issue and that's all I was able to find. Well, there's probably more, but those looked the most clear cut (that is: I understood the answer and it was marked as having solved the problem). Try reinstalling both VS and Unity (at the same time: remove both, then reinstall).

Comment: Have you tried deleting .csproj and .sln and regenerating them?